# Datatables export data not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to export my table data to an Excel spreadsheet.

I followed the guide lines [here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/collection.html), and the options are not working.It is working fine in mozilla but not in chrome.

Here is my JS code I am using:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "../swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
             "aButtons": [
                "copy",
                "print",
                {
                    "sExtends":    "collection",
                    "sButtonText": "Save",
                    "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
                }
            ]
        }
    } );
```

I'm not getting the export options. I included the `jquery.dataTables` and `dataTables.tableTools` js files. Is there any other configuration needed to get export these options?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to get the buttons working unless it loads ".swf file".

make sure that you have added "copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" file to your path you've mentioned in DataTable's configuration here

> "sSwfPath": "**../swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf**",

**Edit 1**

This is a sample syntax that works for me here:

```
$(selector).dataTable({
        "bStateSave": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0] }
        ],
        "sDom": 'lfrtip T',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "../data-tables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": ["copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf"]
        }
    });
```

HTH!

Comment: I included swf file also

Comment: check in browser console if it's being loaded! OR, does it throw any error while loading or after you click  export button(s)?

Comment: see my edit. I added picture. While click on pdf, excel options nothing will happen. I didn't get any errors in console.

Comment: Answer edited! please check the sample code if it works! I suspect there's a configuration issue or swf file not being loaded. (Keep the browser console open and watch for any error messages when the page loads!)

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked many, many times. Cannot find an *exact* match, so dont think it should be marked as an actually duplicate. dataTables `sSwfPath` really dont like relative paths. Either use an absolute path pointing to your own server / website, or use the new dataTables CDN, like :

```
...
sSwfPath : 'http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf'
...
```

see the full CDN list of dataTables TableTools here -> **http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/**

see full list of resources for each version, here 2.2.3 -> **http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/** the `swf` file listing is the last section of the page.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue in chrome: Adobe Flash Player was disable in chrome,
check your Flash is enable in browser.
Chrome:  `chrome://plugins/`

Answer (score -1):

You should enable flash in Google Chrome with `chrome://settings/content/flash` 
or add the host server address.